# how to get a syllable signed as "anceps" with the metre package?

Tags: positioning, poetry, overset

I want to quantify verses with the metre package. Problem is to position the "anceps"-sign (a little "x") over a vowel.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{metre}
\begin{document}

\begin{metrica}
    \InterPedes{2.5}
    \centerline{\metra{\M\b\n1\b \s \M\b\n2\b \s \M\b\n3\b \s \M\b\n4\b \s \M\b\n5\b \s \M\n6\a}}
\end{metrica}   

Sign for a socalled anceps syllable: \metra{\a} 

Daktylus: \metra{\M\b\b}  
Spondeus: \metra{\M\m}  
pic of the last metre of a hexameter, the \glqq x\grqq\ shall appear above a vowel, needed in last word \glqq nostra\grqq, see below: \metra{\M\a}  

\begin{metrica}  
      \Elevatio{1.75}  
    \ldots gl\='or\-i\-a n\='ostr\={a}!\grqq  
\end{metrica}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: no classicists en route?

Comment: See [memoir class and metre package incompatible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380472/) for a bug in `metre.sty`, at least until version 1.0, released 2001/12/05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `metre` package does not seem to offer an anceps over a character. Using `\overset` from `amsmath` a custom command for anceps can be defined. Overset works in math mode, therefore the argument needs to be enclosed in `\text`. The default overset is directly on top of the character, this can be raised a bit using `\raise` in order to get the annotation at the same height as the macron and breve. However, not all characters are the same height, so you need to subtract the height of the character from a fixed amount to obtain a consistent value for the raise.

Note that `amsmath` issues a warning that it cannot redefine `\breve` (which is already defined by `metre`), but this does not seem to cause further problems.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{metre}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylen}
\newlength{\curlen}
\newcommand{\anceps}[1]{%
\settoheight{\mylen}{#1}%
\setlength{\curlen}{8pt}%
\addtolength{\curlen}{-\mylen}%
$\overset{\raise\curlen\hbox{\metra{\a}}}{\text{#1}}$}

\begin{metrica}
    \InterPedes{2.5}
    \centerline{\metra{\M\b\n1\b \s \M\b\n2\b \s \M\b\n3\b \s \M\b\n4\b \s \M\b\n5\b \s \M\n6\a}}
\end{metrica}\\
Sign for a socalled anceps syllable: \metra{\a}\\
Daktylus: \metra{\M\b\b}\\
Spondeus: \metra{\M\m}\\
pic of the last metre of a hexameter, the \glqq x\grqq\ shall appear above a vowel, needed in last word \glqq nostra\grqq, see below: \metra{\M\a}  

\begin{metrica}  
      \Elevatio{1.75}  
    \ldots gl\='or\-i\-a n\='ostr\anceps{a}!\grqq  
\end{metrica}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]