# memoir class and metre package incompatible?

Tags: memoir, metre

Trying to use the `metre` package with the `memoir` class something seems to be broken:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{metre}
\begin{document}
\metra{\b\m}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: output in memoir].

Changing to `article` class produces the expected

[image: output in article].

Comment: It was a bug in `metre.sty`, after all.

Comment: Unfortunately, the mail address in the manual of `metre.sty` is invalid, so I couldn't file a bug report.

Comment: @egreg Seeing that none of his packages have been updated for more than 10 years one could assume that they're currently unmaintained.  In that case, for the bug to be fixed in the package itself, it will require a new maintainer, or is there any other provision for cases like that?

Comment: There is a procedure for adopting an abandoned package released under LPPL 1.3, see https://www.latex-project.org/lppl/lppl-1-3c/#maintenance-of-the-work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Found the bug!

The bug is in `metre.sty`, that does

```
\renewcommand{\rs@size@warning}[2]{\relax}
```

whereas the original macro has ***three*** arguments. For some reasons, the fact that `memoir` redefines `\tiny` to be a point larger than article triggers the bug.

## Solution

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{metre}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\rs@size@warning}[3]{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\metra{\b\m}

\end{document}
```

---

### Original answer

It's quite an obscure bug; for some reason, the contents of `\RSsmallest` is typeset rather than being passed to another macro; since the expansion is `6.0pt` and the current font is `cmsy`, you get some strange glyphs.

A workaround is to add something to the preamble, because the bug seems to occur only the first time `\metra` is used.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{metre}

\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{\metra{\b}}}

\begin{document}

\metra{\b\m}

\end{document}
```

In this way, the bug occurs inside an unused box.

[image]